# Error p:ajax update

Tags: java, ajax, primefaces

In an edit screen, I'm using `p:ajax` to grab the selected value in an autocomplete field and fill in other fields in the form. But when ajax is running in question it is updating the information in the database table (update). How do I block this behavior? After all I should only do this when I clicked the save button.

Code:

```
    <h:panelGroup>
        <p:autoComplete id="demandaBeanDemandaLogradouroNome" value="#{demandaBean.demanda.logradouro}"
            var="_item" minQueryLength="3"  maxResults="15" required="true"
            itemLabel="#{_item.nome}" itemValue="#{_item}" converter="#{logradouroBean.converter}"
            completeMethod="#{logradouroBean.buscaLogradouro}" title="Busca pelo Logradouro">
            <p:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{_item.categoria.descricao}"/>
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{_item.nome}"/>
            </p:column>
            <p:ajax partialSubmit="true" immediate="true" event="itemSelect" update="demandaBeanDemandaBairro demandaBeanDemandaCruzamento"
                listener="#{logradouroBean.buscaComplementoSelectEvent}"/>     
        </p:autoComplete>
        <p:message for="demandaBeanDemandaLogradouroNome" styleClass="error"/>  
    </h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: If you'd like to have an answer to your question, make sure to formulate it in english.

Comment: Good Morning,

In an edit screen, I'm using p: ajax to grab the selected value in an autocomplete field and fill in other fields in the form. But when you run the ajax in question it is already updating the information in the database table (update). How do I block this behavior? After all I should only do this when I clicked the save button.

Comment: Please edit your question instead.

Comment: OK. It is edited. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that what happens is that Hibernate synchronizes the persistent objects and if you change it it automatically updates in the database. To solve, I used an auxiliary object with the @Transient tag. Thanks.